# how would I reference 1 line of an array that is in list so that I may pass the value?

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass a value from `special.Day` to `intFileDay` depending on the `events[]`. For example, if I want to get special.Day value from event[3]......how would I reference that so that I can say `intFileDay = event[3].special.Day` ??

```
public List<Event> ExtractData(DateTime dtmDay)
  {
     int intChosenDay = dtmDay.Day;
     int intFileDay;

     StreamReader textIn =
    new StreamReader(
    new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read));

     //create the list
     List<Event> events = new List<Event>();

     string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);


     for (int index = 4; index < lines.Length; index += 5)
     {
        Event special = new Event();
        special.Day = Convert.ToInt32(lines[index - 4]);
        special.Time = (lines[index - 3]);
        special.Price = Convert.ToDouble(lines[index - 2]);
        special.StrEvent = lines[index - 1];
        special.Description = lines[index];
        events.Add(special);
     }



     textIn.Close();

     return events;

  }
```

Comment: You are using a list, not an array. You may call `intFileDay = events[3].Day`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `events[]` is a list of `Event` type, each element will be an `Event`, so you can just do this:

```
int fileDay = events[index].Day;
```

Comment: When I try and use your code, it says "the name index does not exist in the current context. Do I have to add it in the for loop? If so, how can I get the fileDay value in the method?

Comment: I am trying to include: FileDay = events[index].Day;  if (intChosenDay == FileDay) { return events[index] }

Comment: @Jae Just substitue `index` with the value that you need. Or put `int index = 3;` or whatever before that line of code.

Comment: I have a MonthCalendar.SelectionDay that I'm trying pass through Datetime dtmDay in my method so I need that value to equal any of the events[x].Day. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean. You maybe should make a new question, so you can post some code to explain what you're aiming for.